# How to connect a database file remotely using Firebird server

Tags: c#, firebird

I have created an update tool which will update a Firebird Server database to an SQL Server database, this updating is done using  Firebird database backup file and updated to an SQL Server database. I have a Firebird backup file with data up tp 2016, but the client has latest data up to 2018. I want to access his backup file, and for this I have created a Firebird connection string

```
string ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=192.168.1.19:50800:D:\\Company Data\\CLINEDB.CMP;DataSource=192.168.1.19;Charset=NONE;Server Type=1;";
```

I get this error:

> Unable to complete network request to host "50800". failed to establish a connection

If I use this connection string

```
string ConnectionString = "User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;Database=192.168.1.19/50800:D:\\Company Data\\CLINEDB.CMP;;DataSource=192.168.1.19;Charset=NONE;Server Type=1;";
```

> Unable to complete network request  to host "D". failed to locate host machine

Comment: " want to access his backup file" - you can not open back-up file, you first have to recreate a database file from this backup. Which libraries you use to connect to the remote server? `Charset=NONE` is potentially dangerous setting... Try `DataSource=192.168.1.19:50800` or `DataSource=192.168.1.19/5080` and totally remove the server part from `Database=`. It seems you make that remote FB server to act as proxy and try to connect to the next server on your behalf, "server chaining"

Answer (score 3):

Your connection string is wrong:

1. You try to specify the full connection information in `Database`, but you need to specify them separately in `DataSource`, `Port` and `Database`.
2. You also incorrectly try to use Firebird Embedded, while you need to connect to a remote server. So, `Server Type=1` should be left off or be given value `0`.

The right connection string would be:

```
"User ID=sysdba;Password=masterkey;DataSource=192.168.1.19;Port=50800;Database=D:\\Company Data\\CLINEDB.CMP;Charset=NONE;Server Type=0;";
```

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/firebird/

In your question you say you want to connect to a Firebird  *"backup file"*. That is not possible, you can only connect to a real Firebird database.

Comment: i have tried with given connection string im getting error like this "Connection rejected by remote interface" and also how can i find extract port number

Comment: @Amarnath You should ask whoever administers that server. The default port for Firebird is port 3050 (which will also be used if you leave the `Port` property out of the string. _"Connection rejected by remote interface"_ may also mean this is a Firebird 3 server which requires wire protocol encryption. It will need to be set to Enabled (or Disabled) for the Firebird ADO.net provider to be able to connect.

Comment: I do, but many people who regularly post on SO don't like their comments being edited. And trying to guess does not work always.

Comment: very sorry to bother, still i am getting error "unable to complete network request to host '192.168.1.11' even i enabled the "Wirecrypt=Enable" that removed # from firebird.config file. still i am getting error.

Comment: @Amarnath The setting is `WireCrypt=Enabled` (ending in a `d`), and otherwise it suggests that there is no Firebird server listening at the ip+port specified

Comment: just it was spelling mistake what i typed in message, but still i am getting error could you help what i have to do

Comment: @Amarnath Sorry, I've run out of idea other than that there is not actually a Firebird service running.

Comment: i am not understand "not actually a firebird service running" means Firebird server was not running

Comment: @Amarnath The error you posted in your comment yesterday suggests that there is no Firebird server running (or at least not on the ip-address and port you're trying). If there is no Firebird server running, then you can't connect to it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thanks for helping at finally i have connected to Database file which is in local Network. i want to connect client system database file, i have his ip address like '192.168.1.12' and when i search in google ip address it show '182.165.23.234'. so how could i connect when it is like this. and these ip addresses are sample only

Comment: 192.168.*.* is internal networks only, you can't connect to those IP addresses over the internet. And, exposing database servers over the internet is not a good idea. If you need to connect to remote database servers from your clients, then you should use a VPN or SSH tunneling solution so you can connect to their network, or if that is really not an option, then those database servers should be shielded by a firewall that has your IP address (range) whitelisted for access. However, that is really a broad subject and frankly off topic for stack overflow.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you but i have to use any one them you what you mention VPN or SSH or firewall how could i do and i don;t have any option for me